# Привязка базы данных к ComboBox

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, entity-framework, mvvm

1. Как правильно привязать данные из базы данных к `ComboBox`, чтобы в нем всегда были актуальные данные для выборки, с использованием `MVVM`?
2. Как сделать возможность не просто выбора элемента из `ComboBox`, а дать пользователю еще и возможность ввода название элемента с возможностью автодополнения.

Допустим пользователю нужно выбрать название города. Он вводит `"М"` и сразу появляется подсказка `"Мадрид"`, но если он продолжает вводить название которого нет в базе, допустим `"Мюнхен"`, то снизу должно появиться поле с возможностью выбрать из какой страны этот город.

Comment: Когда-то давным давно делал примерно так: http://selo-blog.blogspot.de/2009/09/wpf-xmldocument-itemsource.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Довольно объемные вопросы.

1. Какого-то одного прям правильного способа нет. Я использую Entyty Framework и в `ViewModel` держу коллекцию с нужными элементами, периодически ее обновляя при изменении контекста и прочих событий.

```cs
public ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel> AccountList
        => new ObservableCollection<AccountViewModel>(_dataService.GetAccounts().Select(a => new AccountViewModel(a)));
```

Здесь же можно добавить `Where` для фильтрации или чего угодно.

2. Вообще целая инженерная задача, в полной мере реализовать непросто, нужно свой юзерконтрол. `ComboBox` не предоставляет нужного функционала, нужно искать сторонний контрол, либо писать свой с нуля или на основе `ComboBox`.